# character encoding issue with the BCP and ó

Tags: sql-server, unicode, character-encoding, bcp

I have a file that needs to go to Poland.  In my data I have an `ó`.  When I output the data to a table the `ó` is still there as the field is `NVARCHAR`.  When I cut and paste from the table into Excel or Notepad++ the `ó` stays

When I use the BCP utility to export the data, the `ó` is changed to a `¢` if I open the resulting text file in Excel or Notepad++.  If I change the encoding sometimes the character becomes a `˘`.

I have tried the following command line switches, one at a time.
`-n`
`-N`
`-w`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you looked into `-C`?

```
-C { ACP | OEM | RAW | code_page }

    Specifies the code page of the data in the data file. code_page is
    relevant only if the data contains char, varchar, or text columns
    with character values greater than 127 or less than 32.
```

Given your table's data type is Unicode (NVARCHAR), you also have to use `-c` (which may lose some Unicode characters)

```
-c
    Performs the operation using a character data type. This option
    does not prompt for each field; it uses char as the storage type,
    without prefixes and with \t (tab character) as the field
    separator and \r\n (newline character) as the row terminator. -c
    is not compatible with -w.

    For more information, see [Use Character Format to Import or
    Export Data (SQL Server)].
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [test] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
);  

INSERT [dbo].[Test] ([test]) VALUES (N'helló wórld');
```

---

```
bcp dbo.Test out dbo.Test.dat -c -T -C ACP
```

`-w` without `-c` and `-C ACP` should also work as long as Notepad++ can detect the encoding (UCS-2 Little Endian). I had no problem with my simple example using Notepad++ 6.7.7.

[image: Notepad++]

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Comment: You saved me
Thank you very very much